# Meaning of って in レニーって男が来て脅されたんだよ

Tags: grammar, translation

Does the って in the レニーって男が来て脅されたんだよ refer to Lenny being the party who threatens the man?

Lenny is a thug

I think the sentence reads Lenny threatened a man who came.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> レニーって男が来て脅されたんだよ

We'd normally interpret it as...

(*lit.*) "A man called Lenny came, and I was threatened (by him)."
→ "A man called Lenny came and threatened me."

The って is a colloquial version of という.
レニー**って**男 = レニー**という**男

Comment: Many thanks @Chocolate. This version fits the storyline well.

Answer (score 1):

「レニーって男」 is "a man called Lenny".

Whether he was the threatening or the threatened party depends on the context you've left out. 「脅される」 is usually to be threatened, but it could be an ironic polite form here.

(update)

With 「んだよ」 on the end, it does seem more likely that it was the man called Lenny who was either threatened or intimidated. Not guaranteed, but you would expect [句点]{くてん} if it were the レニーっていう男 doing the threatening。

> レニーって男が来て、脅されたんだよ

It also might be a bit odd for the intimidater to be spoken of with respect, so we should not expect that reading even with the 句点。 Probably it was the man called Lenny who was threatened.

(woops)

I missed that you had added that Lenny was known to be a thug. That fact (probably) overrides the rest of my theorizing, so that the speaker can be assumed to be the subject rather than the man called Lenny.

(end-woops)

To make one more thing a bit more clear, 「って」 here is an abbreviation of 「っていう」 or 「という」.

(end-update)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It's all clear now. I've edited the question to include context.

Comment: And I've edited my answer. HTH.